# How to generate Thread dumps when JVM terminates automatically

Tags: java, jvm

Problem scenario : The problem is noticed in sonic MF container (The jvm).The container has hosted some java services responsible for db operations and message transformations.Once started, the container runs fine for 2-3 weeks and terminates by its own without throwing any exceptions.

After much research, we are unable to find out why or what has triggered the jvm (MF Container) to shutdown.

Is there a way by which I can get the thread dumps when the jvm goes down automatically ? I'm using java 1.6. Is there any other approach to this problem I should follow ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try [java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29), and have the hook iterate over all threads and dump their stack traces with [Thread.getAllStackTraces()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getAllStackTraces%28%29).  However,  if the JVM was shutdown by `Runtime.halt()` then the hooks won't be called.  More complicated would be to use [instrumentation](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19309.html) to hook into the calls to `Runtime.exit()` and `Runtime.halt()` (or `Shutdown.sequence()`, see edit #2), so you can see exactly what's happening at the time that either is called.

**EDIT**: Another way of doing it would be to install a [SecurityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) which doesn't enforce any security, but which dumps the list of threads whenever `SecurityManager.checkExit()` is invoked, since both `halt()` and `exit()` call that security manager method.  This would be a lot easier than using instrumentation, and you could even decide to throw an exception in addition to logging what the threads are doing.

**EDIT 2**: The system the JVM is running on can tell the JVM to terminate, in which case using a security manager won't work.  Nor will using instrumentation on `Runtime.exit()` or `Runtime.halt()`, since the method that gets invoked is `java.lang.Shutdown.exit()`.  And if the JVM is shutting down because the last daemon thread  finished then `Shutdown.shutdown()` is invoked.  But shutdown hooks **will** work in either of those situations.  So you should always use the shutdown hooks, even if you're also going to use the security manager or instrumentation.

Comment: `have the hook iterate over all threads and dump their stack traces` How is he supposed to do that?

Comment: With java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces().  I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/hangloop.html "Troubleshooting Hanging or Looping Processes"

However, at least in my case, Eclipse is hung, and does not respond to any of these.