# JVM is crashing without any crash dump, crash report ignored by apport

Tags: java, grails, ubuntu, crash, cron

I am having issues on production server, It is groovy/grails application and I am using quartz to run many crons.

There is one cron which is when enabled crashes the JVM. I have no idea why. I can't find any crash dumps or any logs.

I found that the JVM is calling `apport` for crash report but `apport` is ignoring it. I read that `apport` also creates `something.crash` file inside `/var/crash` directory but I don't know it is not creating for Java crashes.

Here's the log from `apport.log` file.

```
ERROR: apport (pid 2150) Fri Sep  5 05:29:31 2014: called for pid 2100, signal 11
ERROR: apport (pid 2150) Fri Sep  5 05:29:31 2014: executable: /usr/local/java/bin/java (command line "/usr/local/java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djvmarg=-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -Xloggc:/usr/local/tomcat/logs/gc.log -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/tomcat/endorsed -classpath /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start")
ERROR: apport (pid 2150) Fri Sep  5 05:29:31 2014: executable does not belong to a package, ignoring
```

Please suggest me how to enable crash dump for apport, I read it only works with packages installed from repo or any other way to make java create crash dump instead of reporting it to apport.

Let me know if you require any more information.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a shutdown hook to dump the stack of all the threads... this helped me track down a System.exit() call once.
Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714828/how-to-generate-thread-dumps-when-jvm-terminates-automatically) question.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that. I don't the shutDown hook getting called, I think it's the tomcat which is crashing and not the JVM.